# can I say“you are an eye opener” “you open my eyes”

Tags: idiomatic-language

when I actually mean you behave in a way that makes my jaw drop, so annoying and so bold or rude.
can the phrase be used as a neutral one and describe a person?

Comment: [***It** was an eye opener, not **He...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+was+an+eye+opener%2CHe+was+an+eye+opener&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Why do you think that saying somebody is annoying or rude could be neutral?

Comment: Because even though you think so， you don't want to be caught saying so

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we say some*thing* is "an eye-opener", not some*one*, which means that it was surprising and educational.

> That documentary was a real eye-opener.

But, we can say that either someone or something "opened my eyes", meaning that they/it has educated you on something you were unaware of, or made something clear to you.

> You have opened my eyes.